# Can the Arellano Bond model accommodate lags of explanatory variables?

Tags: time-series, multiple-regression, linear-model, generalized-moments

The standard type of equation I've seen for the Arellano-Bond is y_it = r* y_it-1 + B*x_it + e_it. The endogenous variable y is a function of y at previous times, x at the current time, and an idiosyncratic error term.

I would like to specify a model where y is a function of y at previous times, x *at previous times*, and an error term. The change is that lags of x, rather than the contemporary value of x, affects y.

Is the Arellano-Bond model still appropriate for this case? If so, does this change the moment conditions?

Thanks in advance for help with a difficult question I am struggling with.